# .babelrc Babel configuration in a Next.js app

Tags: javascript, jestjs, next.js, babeljs, babel-jest

I'm getting my hands dirty with Babel for the 1st time to convert Jest tests from ES6 syntax to commonJS; this will likely involve using the `@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs` babel plugin which I'm trying to install in my Next.js project. Looking at [this](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#file-relative-configuration) part of Babel's configuration docs, I see the term `package` pop up a lot.

Are package hierarchies a Babel convention, Node-defined feature, or part of base JavaScript itself? What exactly defines a package in this context, and where is there documentation for them? Is `babel-jest` a stable alternative to this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Babel uses a `package.json` file to resolve module dependencies. A package is a collection of files which can be imported using the `require()` function. You can read more about packages in the Node.js documentation on packages.

There is no standard way to define a package hierarchy, but Babel does have some conventions for how to organize your files. You can read more about that in the Babel documentation on organizing your code. Babel-jest is a stable alternative to converting Jest tests from ES6 syntax to commonJS. It provides support for using `babel-plugin-transform-modules-commonjs` to convert your modules to CommonJS.

Specifically, in the context of the Babel documentation you mentioned, the word "package" refers to your application itself (which is also considered a package) as well as other applications contained within the same repository (in case you have a monorepo containing many applications).